Fix USB connection without rebooting
OS is Debian. I have a USB switcher set up so that I can use the same keyboard and mouse with two different computers.
I use this switch dozens of times a day. 
For the most part, everything seems to work fine,
but every once in a while
I will run into a problem with my Debian desktop.
When switching from the other computer to the Debian desktop,
the mouse and keyboard just simply won't work.  I can ssh into my desktop
and check that the keyboard and mouse are detected with dmesg.
Toggling the USB switch, I can see the keyboard disconnect and reconnect in dmesg, same with the mouse, no issues there. It just seems like something about Xorg is refusing to use this mouse and keyboard.
When this issue occurs, I try different USB ports also, but same issue:
dmesg shows the keyboard and mouse as being detected,
but seems like Xorg just can't use them.
I don't think it's a hardware problem, as I have had similar issues with USB in the past, with three different motherboards, going back to Debian 8.
Simply rebooting the computer fixes the issue every time,
which, IMO, is more evidence it's not a hardware problem. 
However, I really need to avoid rebooting at all costs as it severely interrupts my workflow. The main reason I use Linux is for stability.
How do I "reboot USB" without rebooting my desktop?
Edit: This happened again today, and it looks like this time lsusb hangs. It will print some devices, then just hang. I then tried unplugging all usb devices and running lsusb again, same issue, and some devices are still printed despite being disconnected.
dmesg has no useful information whatsoever. It just showed that I disconnected each usb device. No errors, no debug output, nothing. How do I get more information for debugging?
So I'm guessing that the USB switcher is defective then? Something about the USB switcher causes the entire USB subsystem to fail when I toggle the USB switcher back and forth? I would have thought that the USB protocol would be more resilient than this, that one bad device wouldn't cause the others to fail, or for lsusb itself to fail.
Also, still not sure what a reboot is accomplishing that can't be done in software without rebooting. Is there really no way to tell Linux "Whatever you're doing with usb when rebooting, do that to usb right now, without actually rebooting the system".

"rebooting the computer fixes the issue every time, which [...] is more evidence it's not a hardware problem" - I'd suggest precisely the opposite

If the physical usb port on my motherboard was fried, how would rebooting fix that?

It wouldn't, but that's only one class of hardware failure. Another might be that the hardware locks up and needs a reset to get it going again. I have seen this on older hardware although the example eludes me just now

Have you checked whether your keyboard still works in console mode? Have you checked whether the keyboard and mouse still send events on the corresponding /dev/input/event device? A guess is that the kernel has run out of minor number for the devices.

My kvm does this on different hardware and different OS's - linux & windows (I own two). I turn it off and back on and it fixes it.


How to reset USB controllers?
in debian (but not redhat it seems) there is apparently a usbutils package that provides usbreset.

https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/usbutils/usbreset.1.en.html
https://superuser.com/questions/141908/how-do-i-reset-an-usb-device-
without-unplugging-it-in-linux
I would try this one first


https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line
https://blog.wesleyac.com/posts/linux-reset-usb
https://www.linux.org/threads/resetting-the-usb-subsystem.10404/


I'd just turn the usb switcher off and then back on.  I do this when my kvm starts going crazy which happens about once every two weeks.  Should be a simple solution.
If that's not to your liking, you could write a script to detect attached keyboards, mice, remove them and then rescan to re-add them.
